# How to log all information about Rabbit MQ?

Tags: logging, rabbitmq

I have a RabbitMq cluster(2 nodes).
1 - master
2 - slave
I want to know all information(include system logs) about RabbitMq servers(errors, connections to it, users, etc.)
And also information when one of my server crashes.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

The logs are usually located inside `/var/log/rabbitmq`

if you what check the status you can use the [management UI](https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html) and/or use the [API](https://cdn.rawgit.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-management/rabbitmq_v3_6_5/priv/www/api/index.html)

Most of monitoring systems use the management API to monitor RabbitMQ